# How to get specific category name from previous page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get a specific category name that was used in previous page before clicking on a post.

When you you're in apple valley location page (apple valley location category) and if I click on The maple home plan
[image]

I want to get a location category name that came from previous page. Note: the Maple homeplan can be used in other category location names so I can't use the get category function from Wordpress because it will show me more than one location category.

I hope this makes sense. Please help.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use referer to get previous post and get its categories.

```php
$previous_url = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
// if you're using PHP >= 7
$previous_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?? null;

if ( $previous_url ) {

    $pieces = array_filter( explode( '/', $previous_url ) );

    // get the last part of the path. 
    // It must be the post slug. You can adapt to what you need
    $slug = end($pieces);

    // get wordpress post
    $posts = get_posts(['name' => $slug ]);

    var_dump( $posts[0] ); // must be your post from previous page, 
                           // I recommend to verify if exists 

    $categories = wp_get_post_categories( $posts[0]->ID );
    // there are the post categories

} else {
    // if link was visited directly PHP will not set HTTP_REFERER
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but I hope it helps you with the code logic.